# readframes return 2 byte in python

Tags: python, wav, frequency, sampling

When `readframes()` is used in python, the [online documention](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.readframes) says sampling frequency is returned it looks it returns 2 bytes. I think there are 4 byte on each frame:

```
left = 2 bytes
right = 2 bytes
```

Do I have to check if it is mono or stereo and if it is stereo, read 2 frames at a time and if it is mono, read 1 frame at a time?

Comment: I think you'll have to provide more detail, such as what library are you using? what exact wav format is it?

Comment: @Keith Added some context. The tagging gave it away ;)

Comment: oh sorry not a getframes it's readframes sorry

Comment: @kim taeyun pydoc.org is hopelessly outdated in favor of http://docs.python.org/ . I updated your link to the latter; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: What is the Bits per sample resolution of the signal? If it's 16 bps, you'll get two bytes per frame.

Comment: I used built in library "wave" thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A wave file has:

- sample rate of [`Wave_read.getframerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getframerate) per second (e.g 44100 if from an audio CD).
- sample width of [`Wave_read.getsampwidth()`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getsampwidth) bytes (i.e 1 for 8-bit samples, 2 for 16-bit samples)
- [`Wave_read.getnchannels()`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getnchannels) channels (typically 1 for mono, 2 for stereo)

Every time you do a [`Wave_read.getframes(N)`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.readframes), you get **`N * sample_width * n_channels`** bytes.

So, if you read 2048 frames from a 44100Hz, 16-bit stereo file, you get 8192 bytes as a result.